# Наименование классов стилей

Tags: css

Разбираю стили сайта и обратил внимание, что часть классов и id стилей именуется с дефисом, а часть с подчёркиванием.
Например:

```
 .lead-top {
    background-color: #8f9f9f;
}
.product_cart {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Есть ли какие-то рекомендации по наименованию классов стилей? Что правильнее использовать - подчерккивание или дефис?

Comment: что больше нравится - то и используй

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с дефисом более распространенный. Если вы устроитесь на работу то в большинстве случаев в вашей команде будет использоваться именно этот вариант. Конечно, никто вам не запрещает использование подчеркиваний, но мой совет - используйте дефисы, все любят "шашлык" :)

Comment: а как же camel case? все любят шашлычек на шампурчеке без пустых мест?)

Comment: На сколько я знаю CSS не чувствителен к регистру, поэтому как такового camel case в нём нет :)

Comment: чувствителен)----